# Customize NavigationLink to have a title and align the arrow?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Is it possible to customize the NavigationLink-view? I want to have some kind of "title", and also move the arrow up to align with this title (like it is in i.e. Apple Health).

So:

1. Is there some kind of modifier to NavigationLink to add this "Title" without messing with Text() and VStack and various modifiers to get the placement right?
2. Is it possible to align the arrow in line with the title, instead of vertically centered in the cell?

[image: Illustration]

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Title")
                            .padding(.bottom, 8)
                            .offset(x: -20)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        Label("Test", systemImage: "bolt")
                    }
                }
                .padding(10)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I didn't found any modifiers for `NavigationLink` or List-views, so I made a custom version of `NavigationLink`. I'll post it here if someone else needs it:

```
struct MyNavigationLink<Destination:View, Content:View>: View {
    let title: String?
    let destination: Destination
    let content: Content
    
    init(title: String?, destination: Destination, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.destination = destination
        self.content = content()
        self.title = title
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                if let title = title {
                    Text(title)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.small)
            }
              .overlay(NavigationLink(
                        destination:  destination,
                        label: {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    ))
            HStack {
                content
                    .padding(.top, 1)
                    .padding(.bottom, 8)
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can customize the navigation link in the label closure in its initializer